# Regex Replace: Match hypen not preceded by slash

Tags: c#, regex

How can i replace Hypen's inside a string, but ignore hypens preceded by a slash eg: "Just-Testing-A-String-\--But i want to leave this hypen"

Comment: Danm, this one is making me think!

Comment: Do you want to leave \- or \--?

Comment: Pet peeve: the \ character is the *backslash*.  The slash is the / character, also known as the forward slash.  Carry on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep only one hyphen that follows the \, then you can use regex

```
(?<!\\)-
```

UPDATE:
Actually I don't believe that it is possible to create such a rexeg, because in this case you would have to do two replacements: one is for

```
'-' to ' '
```

and another one is for

```
'\-' to '-',
```

so you need to run two replacements. The only thing I can think of is if you OK with replacing '\' with ' ' also. Then you can use the following regex

```
((?<!\\)-)|(\\(?=-))
```

Comment: That leaves `\-` in the output. I believe the author wants `-` left where `\-` was.

Comment: Thats correct. Its bacically a string and i need to replace hypens with spaces, but sometimes may need to have a hypen in hence the \-

Comment: I see. That would be more complicated. Maybe it's easier to run two different replaces one by one. First is the one I indicated and the next one is to remove \

Comment: Think thats the way to go. Thank you

Comment: And that will do it accompanied by a replace for double spaces

Comment: But that would only work if you run replaces one by one. You cannot run them in one regex, because at the time the search is done there would be no double spaces. This would'n work "((?<!\\\)-)|(\\\(?=-))|(  )"

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

regex ([^\\])-

replace with $1YOURSTRING

Comment: FYI - A reference for this method of "negative look-behind" is http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?  I would go about this in different ways depending on the language being used.

The backslash in your example is actually creating an invalid escape character, "-" will throw an error in most languages.  Could you mean a foreword slash, "/"?